# How to debug a C# service that stops for no reason on production server

Tags: c#, service

We have implemented a pair of services in C# that send and receive faxes. These services have been running flawlessly for several years on several servers - until last week.
One of our clients upgraded to Windows Server 2012. We installed the services and all hellbroke loose.
Basically, one of the services appears to work for several minutes, and then, for some unknown reason - goes to the OnStop method. So someone, or something - is stopping it, but I don't know what it is.
How could I go about debugging this? I am new to C# and this is not my code.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Logging, logging, logging.

Comment: Have you checked the event viewer?  If your windows service raises an uncaught exception it should show up in Event Viewer \ Application Log  as an error.

Comment: What's your EventLog syas

Comment: thank you all for helping! I did not think to check the Window event log, only our log. I now see that I'm getting the following message before terminating "System.TimeoutException: WSE832: The thread exceeded the executionTimeout limit while processing a message." We are using WSE3.0 to communicate between the two services. Our timeout is set to 60 seconds in the config file - I'll try upping that and seeing what happens.

Comment: I don't know what could be causing a timeout though... this had never happened...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is interesting the fact you are sending and receiving faxes: It colud  be related to some [Session 0 Insolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463353.aspx) introduced with windows server 2008/2012, that could cause problem in graphic related services.
If you have some chanches to run the server on a developement machine, using a Windows7/8 box and a SYSTEM user, you can probably reproduce the problem.

Comment: Felice - thanks for the tip. This is actually really interesting, because we have a graphic component inside the service that errors out. I did not mention this because it is isolated and not really necessary, so I commented it out for now until I get the main problem fixed. I'll definitely look into that later. Thank you!

Comment: @user884248 do you moved from 2003-2012 or 2008-2012 ?

Answer (score 2):

If it only stops on the production server, it is reasonable that there is something different about the production server than your development server/workstation.

It is probably unlikely that you're allowed to hook a debugger into something on the production server, but the best way to handle this is just to log the he** out of the code.

You should introduce enough logging to figure out:

- Where it stops
- Why it stops (my money is on an exception)
- The state of the application at that time (related to the crash)

This will probably have to be done in iterations, unless you go all out to begin with.

Services and logging go hand in hand, so just implement it.